# VB.NET - Dynamically add in a table row, cells, and an image to each cell according to a directory?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been researching a way to dynamically add a table row, then a set of 3 cells, each containing an image which is pulled from a directory. So far I have found how to dynamically add a row and a cell which I have implemented and thus far I can get it to work, but not the way I had envisioned it. I think it is overwriting the existing table cell/ table row rather than adding a new one each time. Any help would be greatly appreciated or if there is a simpler way than what I have been trying that you may suggest.

Code is as follows:

```
'Populate image array
        Dim FileArr As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\...File Location...\PortImages")

        'Redim Trim Array
        ReDim trimArr(FileArr.Length)

        'Loop through to only get folder and file name from file array
        For y As Integer = 0 To FileArr.Length - 1
            TempName = FileArr(y)
            trimArr(y) = "~" + TempName.ToString.Remove(0, 55)

        Next

        'Determine number of rows needed for 3 images across webpage
        rowCount = FileArr.Length / 3

        'loop through adding table rows as needed
        For x As Integer = 1 To rowCount
            ImageTable.Rows.Add(tRow)

            'Set Row ID
            tRow.ID = "tRow" + CStr(x)

            'Set table row CSS class
            tRow.CssClass = "ImageRow"

            'Loop through each row adding a cell and 1 image
            For z As Integer = 1 To 3
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)

                'Set cell ID
                tCell.ID = "tCell" + CStr(arrCount)

                'set css attribute
                tCell.CssClass = "ImageCell"

                'Add image to cell
                tCell.Controls.Add(newImage)

                'Set image CSS class
                newImage.CssClass = "PortImages"

                'set image to image name
                newImage.ImageUrl = trimArr(arrCount)

                'add one to count
                arrCount += 1

            Next

            'add one to array count for next set of images
            arrCount += 1


        Next
```

Comment: You need to instantiate Row, Cell and other components each time inside the loop(s).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.